# What is a subobject for a type?

Tags: oracle, types

In `all_objects` theres a a column called `SUBOBJECT_NAME`, and the docs say that this is:

> Name of the subobject (for example, partition)

If you do the following query:

```
select * 
  from all_objects
 where owner = 'MDSYS' 
   and object_name = 'SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY'
```

You find that `MDSYS.SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY` has a subobject called `$VNS_1`. What is it? How can types have subobjects?

Comment: Quick google gives me the impression that it means child objects

Comment: Your example query uses ALL_TYPES instead of ALL_OBJECTS, which confuses your question.

Comment: whoops, used the wrong query :/

Comment: Just curious - what do you get when you run SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = '$VNS_1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the documentation means *exactly what it says*.

By way of illustration, I have a table called `RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE` which has three partitions.  I run the pertinent query against ALL_OBJECTS, and lo!

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type, subobject_name
  2  from all_objects
  3  where object_name = 'RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE'
  4  /

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         SUBOBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------- ---------------
RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      TABLE
RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      TABLE PARTITION     SYS_P60
RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      TABLE PARTITION     SYS_P61
RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      TABLE PARTITION     SYS_P62

SQL>
```

I think the problem is the use of the word "objects".  Oracle comes from a time before Object-Oriented Programming (if you can imagine such a thing).  Its data dictionary uses "database object" to mean "thing" - table, view, sequence, procedure, etc.  When Oracle introduced OOP into the database it used the keyword `TYPE`.for these new things.  So the view ALL_OBJECTS is a list of all the *things* your schema has privileges on, not just the user-defined types.

**edit**

Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with type inheritence.

```
SQL> create type my_type as object (attr1 number) not final
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create type my_sub_1 under my_type (attr2 date)
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> select object_name, object_type, subobject_name
  2  from all_objects
  3  where object_name = 'MY_TYPE'
  4  /

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE         SUBOBJECT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------- ---------------
MY_TYPE                        TYPE

SQL>
```

Inheritence is shown by the USER/ALL/DBA_TYPES view, which shows the supertype of the derived type:...

```
SQL> select type_name, supertype_name
  2  from all_types
  3  where type_name in ('MY_TYPE', 'MY_SUB_1')
  4  /

TYPE_NAME                      SUPERTYPE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
MY_SUB_1                       MY_TYPE
MY_TYPE

SQL>
```

**edit2**

TheCoop points out:

> types can't have partitions

In the specific case they cites `$VNS_1` is an artefact of Type Evolution.  When we execute an ALTER TYPE after that Type has been in use Oracle creates a version of it.  We can see this in the %_TYPE_VERSIONS views....

```
SQL> select * from dba_type_versions
  2  where owner = 'MDSYS'
  3  and type_name = 'SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY'
  4  /

OWNER                          TYPE_NAME                        VERSION#
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
TYPECODE                       STATUS        LINE
------------------------------ ------- ----------
TEXT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HASHCODE
----------------------------------
MDSYS                          SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY                    1
COLLECTION                     VALID            1
type SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY
61EB9AEC10198F71C141D13B32F52C00A8

MDSYS                          SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY                    1
COLLECTION                     VALID            2
                                        as VARRAY (1000000) of SDO_TGL_OBJECT
61EB9AEC10198F71C141D13B32F52C00A8

MDSYS                          SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY                    2
COLLECTION                     VALID            1
type SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY
6184209BAEF1F731B937760C2BA8B45688

MDSYS                          SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY                    2
COLLECTION                     VALID            2
                                        as VARRAY (1000000) of SDO_TGL_OBJECT
6184209BAEF1F731B937760C2BA8B45688

MDSYS                          SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY                    2
COLLECTION                     VALID            3
  alter type SDO_TGL_OBJECT_ARRAY modify limit 10000000 cascade
6184209BAEF1F731B937760C2BA8B45688


SQL>
```

[Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjadv.htm#sthref893).

Comment: But, as far as I know, types can't have partitions. So this column must mean something else when the object is a type, but I can't find information on what it does mean for a type.